# passing parsed json data to template

Tags: node.js, ejs

Parsing JSON data from openweathermaps. Console.log works, but data won't pass to ejs template. I keep getting "data undefined" error.

Viewed numerous video tutorials, Teaching assistants, but nothing catching. Seems like a simple thing, just overlooking some small detail. Or maybe it needs an entire rewrite.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    let apiKey = "***************************";
    let city = "Providence,US";
    let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
    q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`;

  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      let weather = JSON.parse(body);
      let data = `temp ${weather.main.temp}  wind ${weather.wind.speed} 
      from ${weather.wind.deg}`;
      res.locals.weather = data;
      console.log(data);
      res.locals.error = null;
      next();
      } else {
      res.locals.data = null;
      res.locals.error = "There was an error current weather data.";
      next();
      }
    });
  });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index",  {data: data});
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING!");
});
```

Console.log yields parsed temperature, wind and direction. Running in the browser yields error "ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at app.get (/workspace/UdemyWebDev/c9Backup/weatherCall/app.js:42:30)", pointing to the {data: data} object in the res.render callback.
Using res.locals is still a mystery after hours puzzling over it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its because scope of `data` is local to middleware function i.e within `app.use(function (req, res, next) { /* */});` hence it will not be available for your endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Shubham. What I ended up figuring out was how to use the correct object pair as seen in the following code, in addition to a small change in the middleware:

Answer (score 1):

What I found was that choosing an arbitrary local variable name (key) tied to the weather object and then using the key: weather pair produces defined values. Then plug the key.parameter.parameter.etc...into the template displays the data. EUREKA!
...but then I got home and went to the cloud ide I was just on, and no soap. Back to the drawing board...

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {
    let weather = JSON.parse(body);
         console.log(weather);
        res.locals.key = weather;
        next();
    });
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index", {key: weather});
    });

**Now, in the template:**

<ul class="key">
                <li>
                    <%= key.name %>
                </li>
                <li class="cur">
                    Temp: <%= key.main.temp %> f
                </li>
                <li class="cur">
                    Press: <%= key.main.pressure %> mb
                </li>
                <li class="cur">
                    RH: <%= key.main.humidity %> %
                </li>
                <li class="cur">
                    Speed: <%= key.wind.speed %> mph
                </li>
                <li class="cur">
                    Dir: <%= key.wind.deg %> deg
                </li>
                <li class="cur">
                    wx: <%= key.weather.description %> deg
                </li>
            </ul>
```

All fine and dandy.